# Emails from my domain getting blocked at all other domains

Tags: email-server, spam, ip-blocking

Recently I tried to set up a new email server using iRedMail on Lubuntu.

The mail server workes very well when email conversation is in the same domain.

But when a user tries to send email to some of the most popular domains like gmail, hotmail or yahoo; all the emails are blocked.

I tried to send an email to my gmail account, this is error response I got.

> host gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.130.27] said: 550-5.7.1
>   [XX.XX.XX.XX      12] Our system has detected that this message is
>   550-5.7.1 likely unsolicited mail. To reduce the amount of spam sent
>   to Gmail, 550-5.7.1 this message has been blocked. Please visit
>   550-5.7.1
>   http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=188131 for
>   550 5.7.1 more information. g12si14338274pat.29 - gsmtp (in reply to
>   end of DATA command)

The XX.XX.XX.XX part is my IP.

Latter I found that my ip is added to black list at [Spamhaus](https://www.spamhaus.org/pbl/). I requested them to remove my IP. They accepted my request. It also suggested to activate the smtp authentication.

But it was already set to yes as given below.

```
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
```

After a few hours, I again tried to send a mail to my gmail account, again same msg is replied.
When I check the spamhaus database, my ip is also there.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the mess. The problem was in other configurations of my main.cf file. It would have much easier for you guys if had posted that part.

Still thank you all of you guys.

The value for

> smtpd_sasl_local_domain =

was not set. Hence the postfix was not using the smtp authentication.

The new values are

> smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $mydomain

Now the smtp authentication works just fine.

Answer (score -1):

There are a number of possibilities depending on your setup.

The most likely is if your network is infected and sending out spam email as part of a botnet then that issue has to be dealt with first. Otherwise you will be continually added to blacklists. You need to check all machines on the network for viruses.

The second possibility, although you haven't mentioned it, is that this is a home setup and you are trying to send email from a dynamic IP address. If this is the case you will need to send out through your ISP and not directly to the recipient. You need to contact your ISP about this if this is the case.

Comment: Yes this a home setup. But I also have a static ip. I tried a lot, and now I know that the smtp authentication is not working.